# How to make bitlord or other torrent client faster?

Tags: internet, bittorrent

How to increase the download rate of torrent files?
How to make bitlord or other torrent client faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For BitLord specifically, you might find that you are being blocked by some trackers or other bittorrent clients as it is considered a "selfish" client (as mentioned in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitLord amongst many other places) so using a different client might in some cases get you connected to more/"better" peers.

More generally:

1. Try to make your client are "connectible" if it is not already - this increases the potential pool of clients you can be connected to. How to do this depends upon your network setup which you don't detail in your question, but [this page](http://wiki.themixingbowl.org/How_to_become_connectable)  has detail on the subject and maybe helpful to you.
2. Ask your bittorrent client to limit the outgoing traffic so that it does not saturate your upstream bandwidth (which will have a throttling effect on the downstream). The usual recommendation is around 80% (so if you can usually push 100Kbyte/sec upstream, set the throttle to 80Kbyte/sec).
3. *Don't* limit the upload rate too much. The more you upload, the faster the swarm, the faster the swarm in general the faster your overall download is likely to be. Depending on the properties of the torrent swarms you are taking part in a small amount of extra upload can make a surprising amount of difference (i.e. when there are a small number of seeds relative to the total number of peers).
4. Don't take part in too many swarms at once if you don't have a load of upstream bandwidth - otherwise the amount you can upload to each swarm is limited (see point 3)
5. Avoid torrents with many peers but few seeds on public trackers, these never move fast because of the number of people downloading as quick as they can but uploading barely anything. Though this is not usually a significant issue with legal content unless the content is relatively old so most of the seeds have dropped off.

Comment: +1 ditch BitLord. It is a terrible, terrible client, both outdated in code terms and obnoxious to use. Switch to any modern client (the usual recommendation is µTorrent).